# Pull values from two different array lists?

Tags: c#, arraylist, indexing

I need help on how to make a for loop. Then using the i value as both arrayList index numbers.

My directions say
-Create a   loop    that    uses    either  the length  of  the ArrayList   or  the element to  dictate the number  of  times the   loop    will    run.
-Each   time    the loop    runs,   pull    another element of  the ArrayList   and output  it  in  a
meaningful  fashion to  the console.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        nameArrayLists();
    }

    public static void nameArrayLists() {

        ArrayList teamLists = new ArrayList() {"Cloud 9"};

        teamLists.Add("Fnatic");
        teamLists.Add("SKT T1");
        teamLists.Add("Flash Wolves");
        teamLists.Add("EDG");


        ArrayList region = new ArrayList() { "North America" };

        region.Add("Europe");
        region.Add("Korea");
        region.Add("Taiwan");
        region.Add("China");
```

So after this, how do I make a for loop using i as both arrayList index numbers? The end result should be like "Fnatic is in the Europe region, cloud 9 is the in north america region" etc.

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop generally?

Comment: Dota 2 fan here we are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
if (teamLists.Count == region.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < teamLists.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is in the {1} region", teamLists[i], region[i]);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Items in the collections are not matching");
}
```

Keep in mind: Both the list are in the same order. which means for any `i` the value at corresponding index should be matching.

There is a best option for you:

Create a simple class with two properties(more if needed), then an overrided `ToString()` method which is for displaying the text as you described. and then use a List as like the following;

Class definition:

```
public class TeamNRegion
{
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} is in the {1} region", this.TeamName, this.RegionName);
    }
}
```

Then you can create the list of this class objects like this:

```
List<TeamNRegion> teamRegionList = new List<TeamNRegion>()
                                  {
                                    new  TeamNRegion(){Id=1,TeamName="Fnatic",RegionName="Europe"}, 
                                    new  TeamNRegion(){Id=10,TeamName="SKT T1",RegionName="Korea"},
                                    new  TeamNRegion(){Id=11,TeamName="Flash Wolves",RegionName="Taiwan"},
                                    new  TeamNRegion(){Id=12,TeamName="EDG",RegionName="China"},
                                  };

// Print the result like this

foreach (TeamNRegion team in teamRegionList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(team.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Side note: This post answers question as asked. In real coding simply use type to hold both values.